# Are BOOL and bool interchangeable when used with xcdatamodel?

Tags: objective-c, boolean, ios9, xcdatamodel

I have an iOS app that uses CoreData; the *xcdatamodel* has several *boolean* attributes.  My question is: in my objective-c code, are *BOOL* and *bool* interchangeable within those attributes?  The way I've written my code, the logic depends on *true* or *false* (1,0) and yes, I know the difference between BOOL and bool.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't use `BOOL`, or are you asking this in an academic way? What do you mean by "interchangeable within those attributes", too? Are you asking about assigning a `BOOL` to a `bool` and vice versa, or about declaring your properties as `bool` instead of `BOOL`?

Comment: I just did a search, and I have many, many more instances of BOOL in my code rather than bool...

Comment: so the question has answered itself... sort of... thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I recommend you post an answer to your own question with what you discovered; this way you can mark it as the correct answer, and others will benefit from what you've found.